# Head of houshold: Domestic partner, and child, with joint checking

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I am living with my domestic partner and our child, and she contributes about twice what I do into our joint checking account from which all bills are paid. Can she file as head of household? I think she's checking all the right boxes:

- unmarried, filing separately
- claiming a dependent
- effectively pays > 50% of household expenses

Does the joint account make this difficult to establish? This is not in a community property state, if that matters.

**Edit:** I'm wondering what kind of documentation would be necessary in an audit. For example, it seems possible that if our household expenses are low enough that I could pay >50% of them, as long as her income was going toward something else.

Comment: How is this different than if **you** contributed 2x as much as her?

Comment: @RonJohn, I'm not sure what your question means. Sorry. If I contributed 2x as much as her I would not expect she could file as head of household unless we were able to show that she paid all of our bills and more than 3/4 of my income went to non-household expenses. But I think I'm missing something. :)

Comment: (This comment presumes that you're a man.  If you're not, then ignore it...) One word: patriarchy.  If a guy contributed most of the money to running the household, he wouldn't bat an eye at claiming HOH status.

Comment: I think I agree. I just really wanted to make sure the IRS isn't going to be weird about the documentation because I could imagine someone contributing <50% to a joint checking account claiming that they pay >50% of the bills.

Comment: If they audit her, they'll ask for evidence.  But... they do that during **all** audits.  (And they don't audit many people.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since money is fungible<sup>1</sup>, the joint account would make it **easier** to demonstrate that she pays more than half of the household expenses

That's because there's a 2:1 ratio going in, so there's a 2:1 ratio going out, even though which dollars "belong" to who was lost when they got combined.

<sup>1</sup> able to replace or be replaced by another identical item; mutually interchangeable.